# Функция выводит непонятное значение

Tags: c++, функции

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
fn1(int Arg)
{
    int a = 10;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "fn1(): " << fn1(22) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Вызываю функцию и передаю ей число `22` например, что является одним передаваемым аргументом, но функция принимающая один любой аргумент должна преобразовать его в `10`, а у меня почему то выводит `1`, хотя должна вывести `10`,Почему так?

Comment: Ваша функция вообще **ничего не возвращает** :) Как оно у вас вообще скомпилировалось-то?... См. https://ideone.com/xUqSTH

Comment: @Harry в сях предполагался неявный `int`. Надо бы уточнить, где ТС компилировал и как.

Comment: @alexolut Предполагается. Но в сях `cout <<` не предполагается, не правда ли?...

Comment: @Harry я не спорю, что код плюсовый, но допускаю, что где-то есть опции, разрешающие совместимость со старым сишным стилем. Вроде бы в C++Builder что-то такое было.

Comment: вполне возможно, что пример был набросан на доске как черновик с поправкой, что в нем **сознательно** пропущено часть кода. И как домашнее задание - нужно все поисправлять и сделать по условию.

Comment: За что минусанули мой вопрос? нормальный же вопрос, я попросил объяснить мне почему функция выводит такое значение.

Answer (score 2):

Вы неправильно записали функцию, надо:

```
int fn1(int Arg){
    return 10;
}
```

Так как никаких действий функция не делает с аргументами, лучше сразу возвращать значение, и как раз `return` у вас не было. И нужен тип который будет возвращать функция - `int fn1`.

Comment: ПС. Спасибо за правку. Хоть и выше сказали что неявно подразумевается инт, но нас так учили, что все типы лучше указывать явно, вплоть до итераторов.

Comment: Видимо у Вас преподаватель старой закалки(С++98). Я уже забыл когда последний раз объявлял итератор не через auto.

Comment: Наоборот молодой преподаватель, но в целях обучения все таки я бы так же учил сначала писать типы явно, мы еще и свои контейнеры писали на указателях) Самым сложным было написать бинарное дерево опять же на указателях, никто не осилил за заданное время. Но потом понятное дело все брали из std.

Comment: @evilnw надо без итераторов через *range-for* писать!